# Prevent duplication of first drop down option for each row

Tags: jquery

I want to Prevent duplication of first drop down option for each row. I tried the code below. But it does not worked.

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
 $('select:eq(0)').change(function(){
    if($('option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1)
     {
       alert('option is already selected');
       $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());   
     }
  }); 
 });
```

Here I want to alert message when only for the category drop down for each row.

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/y00h1j5x/1/

Comment: Can you elaborate it more precisely? We are not getting what you want to do? Like what is current output and what is your desired output.

Comment: please see my demo. I need when  select the categories(such as fruits,vegi etc..) it must prevent more than one row which select the same option. When execute `$('select:eq(0)').change(function(){}` it does not worked and `$('select').change(function(){}` has worked but it Prevent all options(ie,item1 and item2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update code as follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var row="<tr>"+
           ' <tr>'+
               '<th>category</th>'+
               '<th>item1</th>'+
               '<th>item2</th>'+
           '</tr>';
        $("#table").append(row)
        $("#button").click(
            function () {
                addrow();
            }            
        );
    });





    function addrow()
    {
           var row='<tr>'+
               '<td><select>'+
                        '<option>--select--</option>'+
                        '<option value="1">fruits</option>'+
                         '<option value="2">vegi</option>'+
                         '<option value="3">flowers</option>'+
        '</select></td>'+
        '<td><select>'+
                        '<option>--select--</option>'+
                        '<option value="1">item1</option>'+
                         '<option value="2">item2</option>'+
                         '<option value="3">item3</option>'+
       '</select></td>'+
        '<td><select>'+
                         '<option>--select--</option>'+
                        '<option value="1">item1</option>'+
                         '<option value="2">item2</option>'+
                         '<option value="3">item3</option>'+
       '</select></td></tr>';
        row = $(row);
        row.find("select:eq(0)").change(function(){
       if($('option[value='+$(this).val()+']:selected').length>1){
         alert('option is already selected');
         $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());   
       } 
        });
    $("#table").append(row);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y00h1j5x/4/

Add event only for that element which is new not for all previous elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class to the cell containing the drop down options

```
function addrow()
{
       var row="<tr>"+
              '<tr>'+
           '<td class="category"><select>'+
..............
...............
```

and change the selectors and do something like this:

```
    $("#table").append(row);
    $('.category select').change(function(){
        var selected_val = $(this).val();
        var current = this;
        $('.category select').not(this).each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==selected_val){
                alert('option is already selected');
                $(current).val('');
                return false;
            }    
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnbnnd77/